The $\sigma$-algebra of the Lebesgue measure and the $\sigma$-algebra of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure associated with Cantor function
Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ be the Cantor function. Let $\mu_f$ be its associated (complete) Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure. I am wondering whether the domain of $\mu_f$ contains all Lebesgue measurable sets. In the answer of the following post, $\sigma$-algebra for Lebesgue-Stieltjes Measure, it is claimed that $f^{-1}(A)\cap C$ ($A$ is a non Lebesgue measurable subset of $[0,1]$ and $C$ is the Cantor set) is a Lebesgue measurable set but not $\mu_f$ measurable, but I don't understand why it is not $\mu_f$ measurable.
